# GridDB上でのデータベース管理方法を教えてください

Tags: データベース設計

複数データソースをGridDBに取り込む場合の、GridDB上でのデータベース管理方法を教えてください。
できれば、GridDBのDBを複数に分けたいと思います。可能なんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

DBを複数に分けるようなことは可能です。
なお、DBを分けても、データのフォルダーは1つです（すなわち、フォルダーは分けることはできません）。
また、ユーザは複数のDBにアクセス可能です。ただし、SQLでDBまたがった検索はできません。
詳細は、GridDB 機能リファレンス「7.2.4 データベースユーザ」を参照願います。
[www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/pro/griddb/docs-jp/v5_1/GridDB_FeaturesReference.html#section-66](http://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/pro/griddb/docs-jp/v5_1/GridDB_FeaturesReference.html#section-66)